Excel VBA function that returns dynamic arrays returns #VALUE error
I have an Excel file with a table in a sheet called Category.
Columns are the months of 2024 and rows are unique Customer IDs.
The table shows if the customers are "New", "Active" of "Out of Scope" for each month.
I am trying to create on a separate sheet a dynamic list that takes into argument the month, and shows the IDs of the customers that are

"New" for the selected month
All previous months are "out of scope".

The function should display a list, which length will change depending on the month.
I have come up with this function and a sub that works perfectly in the immediate window, but when typing the function in my Excel sheet as an array formula, it just creates an array of #VALUE.
I tried to get some answers from chatgpt and different forums but I can't resolve the issue.
Function NewCustomer(month As String) As Variant()
    Dim wsCategory As Worksheet
    Dim CustomerID As String
    Dim CustomerIDRange As Variant
    Dim MonthCol As Long
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim tablerange As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim resultindex As Long
    
    Set wsCategory = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Category")
    Set tablerange = wsCategory.Range("B1").CurrentRegion
    Set CustomerIDRange = tablerange.Columns(2)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    MonthCol = wsCategory.Rows(2).Find(What:=month, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If MonthCol = 0 Then
        NewCustomer = Array("no month")
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    ReDim result(1 To tablerange.Rows.Count - 2)

    resultindex = 0
    
    For i = 3 To tablerange.Rows.Count
        If wsCategory.Cells(i, MonthCol).Value = "New" Then
            Dim AllPreviousOutOfScope As Boolean
            AllPreviousOutOfScope = True
            
            For j = 4 To MonthCol - 1
                If wsCategory.Cells(i, j).Value <> "Out Of Scope" Then
                    AllPreviousOutOfScope = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
            
            If AllPreviousOutOfScope Then
               resultindex = resultindex + 1
               result(resultindex) = CustomerIDRange.Cells(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    If resultindex = 0 Then
        NewCustomer = Array("no new customers")
    Else
        ReDim Preserve result(1 To resultindex)
        NewCustomer = result
    End If
     
    Exit Function
End Function


What happens when you run it not from a sheet?

when I run it as a debug.print it works perfectly

CurrentRegion returns one cell (B1 in your case) when called from a sheet.

@GSerg: That would explain that the function returns wrong data, but I guess the reason for #Value is that it returns an array. AFAIK, VBA functions cannot be used for Array formulas

@FunThomas Because tablerange ens up being one cell, tablerange.Rows.Count - 2 ens up being -1.

Use a table (Insert > table) - then you can refer to the range like this: Set tablerange = wsCategory.ListObjects(1).Range
